# Show that $ \lim_{k \to \infty} k^n \int_{(0,k^{-1})^n} f(x)dx=f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f$ be a compact support continuous function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ show that

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} k^n \int_{(0,k^{-1})^n} f(x)dx=f(0)$$

Consider the change of variable $y=kx$ (scalar product by $k$) then
$$k^n \int_{(0,k^{-1})^n} f(x)dx=\int_{(0,1)^n}f\left(\frac{y}{k} \right) dy=\int_{\mathbb R^n} f\left(\frac{y}{k} \right) \chi_{(0,1)^n}(y)dy$$
now let $g_k=f\left(\frac{y}{k} \right) \chi_{(0,1)^n}(y)$ is easy to see that $g_k \to f(0) \chi_{(0,1)^n}(y)$ and that $|g_k| \leq M \chi_{(0,1)^n}(y)$ (the constant $M$ is obtained because $f$ has compact support) and the function $M \chi_{(0,1)^n}(y)$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then by the dominated convergence theorem i conclude that
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R^n} f\left(\frac{y}{k} \right) \chi_{(0,1)^n}(y)dy=f(0)$$
hence
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} k^n \int_{(0,k^{-1})^n} f(x)dx=f(0)$$
these is correct? any suggestion or hint i will be very grateful

Comment: Looks fine to me. :)  Besides, all $(0,1)$ should be $(0,1)^n$.

Comment: There is no need for the compact support assumption. This question was asked recently.

Comment: @Feng thanks! i made the corrections :)

Comment: @copper.hat why no need the compact support assumption?

Comment: $[0,1]^n$ is compact. All you need is for $f$ to be measurable and continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @copper.hat you be right but i work with  $(0,1)^n$ not $[0,1]^n$, if i work with $[0,1]^n$ how you say i only need $f$ continuous at $0$ and measurable, thanks for the observation

Comment: For any $\epsilon>0$ you can find a neighbourhood of $0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ in that neighbourhood. If $k$ is large enough the integration domain is contained in the neighbourhood and so the integral is $< \epsilon$.

Comment: @copper.hat nice¡ this is a good aproach